# CSS3 Media Types: "All" devices vs non-defined

Tags: css, media-type

Is there any difference between:

```
@media all and (min-width: 480px) {
    ...
}
```

and

```
@media (min-width: 480px) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ (W3C Recommendation 19 June 2012)

> I.e. these are identical:
>
> @media all and (min-width:500px) { … }
> @media (min-width:500px) { … }